# Standardizing American or European Decimal values in Python

Tags: python, internationalization, decimal

A user can input 6.500,00 6,500.00 or 6500 or 6.500 or 6,500 to mean `Decimal("6500")`

In python, how can you receive any of those as values as inputs and always return the right value as a `Decimal`?

Comment: Will they always be ints? If so, you can just throw away the dots and commas.

Comment: @tzenderman how do you know that 6.500 is not 6 point 500 then ?

Comment: @Davidmh: Almost a good idea. The only problem is, in French, Polish and several other languages it would be 6 500. So you would have to throw a ways spaces too.

Comment: I am pretty sure that there are certain I18n extensions to Python (one would be ICU wrapper) that could handle both formatting for a Locale and parsing Locale formats. The only trouble is, you need to know what is the preferred user format... It's tied to a Locale, so it's good to show the hint on what format is acceptable.

Comment: Check out the [`locale` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html).

Comment: @PawełDyda throw away spaces too. In fact, if you know it is an int, throw away anything that is not a number. (That is almost as ill defined as the problem at hand).

Comment: @Davidmh it's not necessarily an `int`.

@EL3PHANTEN I think you're right: without the locale, it's pretty much impossible to know what a number means.

@PawełDyda Good point, I didn't know that it was this way in countries like France and Poland!

@MarkRansom thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

some kind of a forloop with a lot of replace.

```
b = ['6.500,00','6,500.00','6.500','6,500','6 500']

for a in b:
    if(',' in a and '.' in a):
            if(a.index(',') > a.index('.')):
                    print a.replace('.','').replace(',','.')
            else:
                    print a.replace(',','')
    elif(',' in a or ' ' in a or '.' in a):
            print a.replace(',','').replace(' ','').replace('.','')
    else:
        print a
```

alltough now you never know if the user really wants to input a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more of investigating and asking people, I found the python [`locale` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) mentioned above by @MarkRansom and also the [Babel module](http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/numbers/#parsing-numbers) that would help with this too. Essentially, if you don't also have the locale, it's practically impossible to know what a number means.